# R: ranking by a factor and by a group

Tags: r, ranking

Hoping anyone knows an easy solution in R.

I have a dataset 'temp' with number of variables:

```
Department  Product  Var1 
  D1         P1       3
  D1         P2       6
  D2         P1       4
  D3         P2       2
  D3         P3       3
```

So `Var1` is numeric.

It is already calculated for each product within each Department.

Now,  I am trying to rank by Product within each Department group.
To get ranking by product was easy:

```
ranked<-transform(temp, rank_Var1= ave(Var1,  FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "average")))
```

But, I can't find how I can possibly put a condition that now rank Var1 needs to be calculated within each Department.

Will highly appreciate any advice.
Thank you

Comment: I would use the `dplyr` package. Perhaps `temp %>% group_by(Department, Product) %>% mutate(ranked = rank(Var1)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[,rank_Var1 := rank(Var1, ties.method = "average"),  by= .(Department, Product)]
```

---

If we are using `ave`, after the 1st argument, we specify the grouping variables,

```
transform(temp, rank_Var1= ave(Var1, Department, Product, 
                 FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "average")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
And I found the answer :)

temp2<-ddply(temp, .(Department), summarize,Product=Product,  rank_Vq= ave(V1,  FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "average")))

Answer (score 0):

Arrange your factors in the order you want:

```
temp$Product<-factor(temp$Product, levels=c("P1", "P2", "P3"))
temp$Department<-factor(temp$Department, levels=c("D1", "D2", "D3"))
```

Then set up your ranking, we'll just add a field called rank to the original dataframe:

```
temp<-transform(temp,rank=ave(1:nrow(temp),Department,FUN=function(x) 
order(Department[x], Product[x])))
```